# Deleting files in WordPress via FTP changes nothing and plugins won't delete

Tags: php, wordpress

There are some very strange things going on with my WordPress install; I have recently moved the site to a new host but I done everything right e.g.

- Changed the domain name in settings
- Moved all files and database over
- Changed WP Config file to the new database name
- Used the search and replace tool on the database

The site itself seems to be working fine, from the front end and the back end, until I do any of the following:

- Delete plugins (plugin cannot be deleted error)
- Install plugins, they install fine and show in the plugins folder when I FTP in, but    they do not show in the plugins list in the WP dashboard

I can edit all of the files in the WP Dashboard e.g. CSS and it makes changes on the site.

But there's more, I tried as a test deleting the WP config file, this should break the site right? Well it didn't it carried on as normal like the file was being pulled from somewhere else, so  I tried deleting the plugins.php file from the admin folder and it didn't break anything, so I inspected the element and it is being pulled from the right place so it's not being pulled form the old server or anything. I do not have cache on the server nor as a plugin.

Also any changes I make to the .htaccess file do not work, e.g. 301 redirects.

The thing I really care about is not being able to install plugins, and activate them!

Any Ideas??

Comment: Could it be permission issues on the server? Also when you migrated the site, did you dump it to a flat sql file and do the find and replace in the sql file before you ran it on the new db? I know you said you ran one, thats just how I do it... maybe dump the new db and look for any instances of the old domain....

Comment: Yeah thanks I'll try dumping it again and searching! The strange thing is though, I have removed all of the files on the the old server, DB included..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in-case anyone else had this problem I will explain what was causing it.

NamesCo updated their servers, which caused our server IP to change.

Comment: Though my situation is different, your answer helped me figure out a solution. Thanks.